# How to send/receive messages to/from Skype from a 3rd party application

Tags: api, skype

I've been researching for quite good amount of time about how to interact with Skype, meaning how to send and receive Skype messages from another application that I'm planning to develop.

I found a lot of things which made me confused. There is Skype API mentioned and used by some libraries (like SkPy), and there is Skype Web SDK, SkypeKit, and others.

When looking on the official Skype dev website (https://dev.skype.com) nothing about these is mentioned, and looks like the Microsoft Bot Framework is where MS is moving everything to (or at least that is what I got).

My question is, what is the current situation now regarding this topic? Is it still safe to build a solution on such libraries as SkPy (which uses Skype HTTP API that I could not find a trace of in the Skype's official docs!, but still, I tested and it's working!). Or I should just think of MS Bots? And is Bot a suitable solution for such use case in the first place? (I feel it's not meant to do so).

Hopefully will get some hints.

Comment: any progress on this ??